# Crossed module structure on $\pi_1$-level of any map $f: X\to Y$

Tags: algebraic-topology

For cofibration $f:A\to X$ we have crossed module $\pi_2(X,A)\to\pi_1(A)$. On other hand, we can change map $f$ to fibration and consider crossed module 
$\pi_1(E)\to\pi_1(P_f)$, where $P_f$ is relative path space and $E$ is homotopy fiber of $f$. Homotopy exact sequence of pair and long exact sequence associated with $E\to P_f\to X$ are essentially the same and judging by action of $\pi_1(A)$ (resp. $\pi_1(P_f)$) these crossed modules are isomorphic. So, looks like isomorphism $\pi_1(A)\cong \pi_1(P_f)$ preserve crossed module structure.

**Question**

Is it true, that for any map of spaces $f:X\to Y$, we can form a crossed module $\pi_1(\mathrm{hofib}(f))\to\pi_1(X)$ using isomorphism $\pi_1(X)\cong \pi_1(P_f)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should make quite clear that you are working in the category of spaces with base point.

Secondly, for any map $f: A \to X$ of pointed spaces the map $\pi_1(F(f)) \to \pi_1(X)$, where $F(f)$ is the homotopy fibre of $f$, may be given the structure of a crossed module.

There are several ways of proving the trickier part,  the second rule for a crossed module, which is that

$$v^{-1}uv=u^a, \text{where } a=\partial v.$$  I prefer emphasis on the $2$-dimensional approach and the interchange law as suggested by the following diagram:

[image: xmod]

which is taken from Proposition 6.2.4 of [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/dbgpsmap5.pdf), for which a pdf is available there. In this picture, $u,v$ can be taken to represent elements of a second relative homotopy  group, the square figure is a constant map, and the vertical pairs represent vertical identities. If you add the columns first and then the rows, you get the left hand side; if you add the rows first and then the columns, you get the right hand side.

I mention that the paper given [here](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/dbgpsmap5.pdf) has a generalisation of this result, giving a homotopy double groupoid of any map of spaces, not pointed.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! One could ask same question about simplicial groups, in particular, if $f:H\to G$ be morphism of simplicial groups, is it true, then $\pi_0(F(f))\to\pi_0(H)$ forms a crossed module? I have some doubts, because $\pi_0(H)$ must act by conjugation on $\pi_0(F(f))$, but usually $F(f)$ is not a normal subgroup in $H$.

Comment: Have a look at this paper: Porter, T. {$n$}-types of simplicial groups and crossed {$n$}-cubes. Topology {32}~(1) (1993) 5--24. It may also be somewhere in his "Crossed menagerie" notes.

Comment: Just noticed this and yes. with regrad to simplicial groups. The easiest case is if $f$ is anfibration i.e. an epimorphism, then the kernel $K(f)$ of $f$ is a simplicial normal subgroup of $H$. Now take $\pi_0$ of the inclusion to get a crossed module.

Comment: As to your other point to work out $F(f)$ you need first to enlarge $H$ so as to convert $f$ into a fibration then proceed as in my earlier comment.

Comment: I noticed that Ronnie's links did not work so here is one of them again: https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/dgpsmap5.pdf